# SharedPreferences not saving most of the time

Tags: android, android-fragments, sharedpreferences

I'm using `SharedPreferences` in a fragment class to store some `R.id` values of `RadioButton`'s I need in other Activities. Everything is working nicely, with a small "but".

There are six `RadioGroup`'s present. If I don't press (even the checked one) a button from the first group, no matter what I change in the others, nothing is saved for the next time I open the Activity. If I do press the first `Radiogroup`, ANYTHING I change is stored.

I even tried checking a button in my code, but didn't work.

`orientationID` is the one that has to be "changed"

Declaration in `onCreateView` inside a fragment

```
SharedPreferences settings = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
initPrefs();
```

`initPrefs()`:

```
     private void initPrefs(){
        if(settings.getBoolean("firstOrientationID", false)){
            frg.check(R.id.button1);
        }
        else if(settings.getBoolean("secondOrientationID", true)){
            frg.check(R.id.button2);
        }
        else frg.check(R.id.button3);
        modeFL = settings.getInt("flMode", 2);
        modeSL = settings.getInt("slMode", -1);
        switch (modeFL){
            case 1:
                lessons.check(R.id.lesson1);
                break;
            case 2:
                lessons.check(R.id.lesson2);
                break;
            case 3:
                lessons.check(R.id.lesson3);
                break;
        }
        if(settings.getBoolean("extraLesson", false)){
            numGroup.check(R.id.lessons_five);
            secLess.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            switch (modeSL){
                case 1:
                    slessons.check(R.id.slesson1);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    slessons.check(R.id.slesson2);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    slessons.check(R.id.slesson3);
                    break;
            }
        }
        else numGroup.check(R.id.lessons_four);

        if(settings.getBoolean("specialYNID", false)){
            spGroupYN.check(R.id.sp_yes);
            specMult.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else spGroupYN.check(R.id.sp_no);

        if(settings.getBoolean("specialMultID", true)){
              spGroup.check(R.id.sp_2x);
        }
        else spGroup.check(R.id.sp_1x);
    }
```

The method called when the "Next" button is pressed to leave the Activity

```
    private void nextButton(){
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("extraLesson", num5.isChecked());
        editor.putBoolean("firstOrientationID", addBtn.isChecked());
        editor.putBoolean("secondOrientationID", addBtn2.isChecked());
        editor.putBoolean("specialYNID", spyes.isChecked());
        editor.putBoolean("specialMultID", sp2x.isChecked());
        editor.putInt("flMode", modeFL);
        editor.putInt("slMode", modeSL);
        editor.commit();
    }
```

Am I missing something? It's my first time with `SharedPreferences`, and I can't find anything relevant online.

Comment: Why are you saving the ids of the buttons? It is completely wrong.

Comment: I want to have specific radiobuttons prechecked when the user opens the activity. I thought it would be better than having multiple switches with "case 1: check(id)"

Should i do it with switches? I thought it was ok since it works, sometimes

Comment: Don't save anything from R.id.* ever. Just use a boolean value and set it to true if the button is checked in your prefs.

Comment: Will try right away!

Comment: Even with booleans, it does exactly the same thing. If frg Radiogroup is changed, everything is saved, if not it discards every change

Comment: Don't use editor.clear() it will get overwrite automatically if the variable exist in SharedPreferences

Comment: Still no luck :( Probably will use a simple file...